# improve sitecore rules editor adding move up and down

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I need to add a buttons to move the rules (up/down/top/bottom) to the default rule editor, there is a way to this?

Here is the default rule editor that we have [image: editor]

Comment: Which rules are you trying to move? The ones along the bottom pane? It's already possible to move the Condition parts of the rules, but not the action (the reason I presume is that order _should_ not matter...)

Comment: Yes I am trying to move the rules on the bottom pane. This change if to improve the readability when you had many rules, for example move "Default" rule to the top...